# Angular HttpClient use URL Params in POST

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

today I tried to send a post-Request that looks like that. `http://host/start?time=123456789` using the following code:

```
    const url = `/start`;
    const myParams = new HttpParams().set('time', toTimestamp(time).toString());
    return this.http.post(url, { headers: this.getHttpHeaders(), params: myParams }));
```

However The request was send without the parameter `http://host/start`. The Parameter was send inside the body of the request. The API does not accept that and I am not allowed to change the API. How could I change my code to include the parameter inside the URL?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can pass with url '/start?time=123456'

Comment: If you are only willing to send a post request like you mentioned you can crate a url string by appending the param and param value in the url and then calling post. but POST does for a purpose send data in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Sanyam, the post request looks like...

```
http.post(url, data, httpOptions)
```

So in your request you are missing the actual body part... since this is a `POST` request. Since you have no control of the API, you can add `null` for the `body` part.

```
return this.http.post(url, null, { headers: this.getHttpHeaders(), params: myParams }));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
return this.http.post(url, { headers: this.getHttpHeaders(), params: myParams }));
```

You are sending parameters in the request body which is what is expected here

1. GET sends data in URL to server for getting data from a resource
2. POST sends params in body to the server for update/creation of
   resource

Follow this order in your request :

```
 http.post(url, data, httpOptions)
```